# Frequency decoder circuit microphone not working?

Tags: pcb, sensor, audio, microphone

Thank you Vladimir - I have I believe corrected the microphone element of the circuit but it is still not working.

I've attached a fresh circuit diagram.

[image: new circuit diagram]

I've added an LED to detect when the circuit is working.
And a microphone to provide input. (Following advice today I've added a 2.4K resistor between mic and +6V, and changed the connections.)
I've used my phone to provide a sound frequency to the microphone.
And attempted to tune the circuit using the potentiometer, but the circuit does not appear to be working.
When the microphone is not connected, the LED lights up.

Some advice about getting an output or an alternative input would be useful.
Thank you very much.
This is the microphone I've used:
https://www.rapidonline.com/r-tech-350095-omni-directional-pcb-mount-microphone-6mm-35-0095

Comment: Electrets need a pullup R. What are you using?  Use 2.2 to 3.3k from Mic+ to V+

Comment: You need to provide a more complete schematic showing the microphone and the LED.

Comment: A very warm welcome to the site. Please can you edit your question and greatly improve it, splitting up the single slab of text into paragraphs and using full stops instead of commas that make really long sentences. The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of the answers it will attract. Again, welcome.

Comment: Thank you for all the responses. I've edited the post and added an edited circuit diagram.

Answer (score 0):

Your microphone's internal amplifier is not powered. In it's specs on page 3 there is correct powering circuit. Resistance you selected seems correct.